# create a simple translator using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a very simple translator with python.
But there's errors with the library I am using.
So, I will put my code, and the error.
Help me to solv it or give me other libraryes with simple code.
my code:

```py
from simple_googletrans import GoogleTrans

t = GoogleTrans()
t.translate('hello world', dest='ar')
```

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transl2.py", line 3, in <module>
    t = GoogleTrans()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\simple_googletrans\__init__.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.translator = googletrans.Translator(service_urls=[service_url], proxies=proxies, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 88, in __init__
    client=self.client, host=self.service_urls[0])
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 44, in __init__
    self.host = host if 'http' in host else 'https://' + host
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Comment: [documentation](https://github.com/suqingdong/simple-googletrans) shows also `t = GoogleTrans(url='translate.google.com', ...)` and maybe you have to add this url in code. This module is 2 years old and Google could change many elements on server and now module may not work as before.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code worked with me:

```
import translators as ts
while True:
    uinput = input('the word')
    tran = (ts.google(uinput, from_language='en', to_language='ar'))
    print (tran)
```